# Display a logo in WooCommerce checkout for a custom Payment plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, payment-gateway

In WooCommerce, I'm working on a custom payment plugin. I'm looking for a solution to add logo on custom payment method like on this screenshot:

[image: example]

Does anybody have idea how to achieve this via functions.php (or how this is added).

Answer (score 0):

To add a payment icon to your payment gateway, you will have to add the following function in your payment gateway plugin Class code:

```php
public function get_icon() {
    $icon_url  = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/images/payment-icon.png';
    $icon_html = sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', $icon_url, $this->method_title );

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', $icon_html, $this->id );
}
```

You will have to adjust the desired icon URL path and icon name from your plugin related icon file.

Note: The [method function `get_icon()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-payment-gateway.php#L326) is part of the `WC_Payment_Gateway` abstract class.